# SQL Reporting Services Expression to evaluate if field is null &| white space

Tags: reporting-services

I'm making a report and in a text box I want to show the Tax ID of a entity if one exists. However if a tax ID doesn't exist then that field is just white space. So if the field is white space I want to show nothing in the text box.

```
IIF(IsNothing(Fields!TAX_ID.Value), "", "Tax ID: " & vbCrLf & Fields!TAX_ID.Value)
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

However IsNothing might not always evaluate it properly. Might try:

```
IIF(Trim(Fields!TAX_ID.Value) = "", "", "Tax ID: " & vbCrLf & Fields!TAX_ID.Value)
```

Answer (score 2):

To compare it to a null value, in VB, this is how you do it:

```
IIF(Trim(Fields!TAX_ID.Value) is nothing , "", "Tax ID: " & vbCrLf & Fields!TAX_ID.Value)
```

Comment: `is nothing` is exactly the way to do it.